# Search from a list of 1 million objects

Tags: algorithm, search

I have a Collection[Any implementation] of 1 million Student objects.

A student object contains First name, Last name and roll  number.

Roll number is unique.

And first name and last name can be duplicate.

I need to write an efficient method that takes first name as parameter and search all the objects containing input parameter as first name.

What should be the Best Data Structure for storing 1 million objects and what will be the fastest algorithm to find objects with matching first name?

Comment: map student name to collections of students with that first name

Comment: If all you have is a list that is not sorted by first name, then your fastest algorithm is a sequential search. If you can pre-process the data, then you can sort the list and use binary search to find the first one, and sequentially move forward to get the rest. Or you could build a dictionary keyed on first name, with a list of all users with that name as the value. Lots of different ways to do this. You need to give us more information about your data structure before we can give a useful answer.

Comment: @JimMischel : My question is all about Best performance. I have 1 Million objects. I want to know, which data Structure  and algorithm would be best to retrieve all objects with matched first name.

Comment: Then the answer provided by @Peekaboo will do it well.

Answer (score 1):

Fastest algorithm will mostly depend on the underlying representation of `Collection[Any implementation]`.

[Hashmap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) may be a good candidate for your task. e.g. Hashmap with **first names** as **keys** and **students** as **values**.

e.g. (Java)

```java
/* first name -> list of students with first name */
Map<String, List<Student>> students = new HashMap<>();
```

Another way, You could also keep a **sorted** (by first name) list of `Students` and implement a [dichotomic search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dichotomic_search).

Comment: How to use HashMap in this case to make the search efficient?

Comment: `HashMap` doesn't require search; it's a direct lookup. You should read up on hash tables: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table